# Audio and Video streaming at the same time using C#

Tags: c#, audio, video, streaming, client

I'd like to create an application client-server in C# (WPF).

On the server side I want to make a capture from few cameras and I want to send a preview to client (monitoring system). 
Apart from that client can select one of the preview and take the audio stream from one of the camera.

What library I can use to get stream from few webcams simultaneously?

What about audio streaming from one of the camera?

I don't know how to synchronize video and audio streaming.

Do you have any idea how to achieve this functionality?

Comment: http://www.red5.org/ - have fun :)

Comment: @Leron, thanks but I have to use .NET not Java